# PyGnuplot install not working

Tags: python, gnuplot

I am trying to get Gnuplot or PyGnuplot running. Using Python 3.6. pip3/pip install PyGnuplot did work but when I try to `import PyGnuplot` this Error is given:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/Desktop/123.py", line 1, in <module>
    import PyGnuplot
  File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyGnuplot.py", line 112, in <module>
    fl = _FigureList()
  File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyGnuplot.py", line 30, in __init__
    proc = _Popen(['gnuplot', '-p'], shell=False, stdin=_PIPE, universal_newlines=True)  # persitant -p
  File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden
```

I tried to copy it manually into Lib folder but it changes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem, but managed to fix it. I had to add the gnuplot directories to the PATH environment variable (while gnuplot installation its possible to choose this by option). Afterwards my PyGnuplot was working fine.
Greetings from Cologne

Comment: could you provide the option of the gnuplot installation? I can't find it anywhere :(